# Graceful Shutdown Spring Kafka

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am writing consumer for a few kafka topics using spring framework and spring Kafka. I have to use spring-kafka 1.3 due to some reason. I have done manual configuration to read all topics, create listener, wrap it in container, then start all of them. I am using batch message listener with manual acknowledgement.

I want the application to stop gracefully on shutdown. I was thinking of putting the consumer to pause, processing all the leftover payload that was fetched, then stop the container. When all containers are stopped, I would have stopped and exit the application. But, older version doesn't have pause method to container, or any way to access the Consumer<K, V> object. Is there any way to achieve this without updating to newer version?

The stop method waits on container to process the payload for a defined timeout value, then stops it, which might cause payload being dropped, or processed twice.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are constructing the Containers yourself, you have access to the Consumers. What if you create a ConsumerService, which holds an internal list of all the consumers used, and you add a shutdown hook to that?

```
@Service
public class ConsumerService {

    private final List<KafkaConsumer> consumers = new ArrayList<KafkaConsumer>();

    public KafkaConsumer<String, String> requestConsumer(){
        var consumer = createConsumer();
        consumers.add(consumer);
        return consumer;   
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        //here do the clean, like for example not ACK the messages, so another consumer can pick them up?
    }

}
```

Comment: The AbstractMessageListenercontainer calls the createConsumer method internally while starting the listener